# An irritating Issue about ruby hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, syntax

Why does ruby sometimes interpret a hash as being a block of code?

For example I have a function called 'required' that takes a hash so I do:

```
required { base_uri: String, endpoints: String, destination: String, credentials: Hash}
```

and it think's it's a block of code and errors with `unexpected tSYMBEG`.

The only way to fix this is to put brackets around it so it reads as:

```
required({ base_uri: String, endpoints: String, destination: String, credentials: Hash})
```

It then starts reading it as a hash (like I want it to).

I'm not bothered about putting brackets around the hash, what's irritating is that it's inconsistent, sometimes that works and sometimes it doesn't.

What's going on?

Comment: How can Ruby distinct hash from block if you don't use parenthesis in this case?

Comment: Just drop the brackets for hash parameters

Comment: @papirtiger absolutely right..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you omitted the parentheses of the method call, you have to omit curly braces around hashes too.

Answer (score 2):

You picked the one way that is least used.   Most common in this case would be to omit both types of punctuation:

```
required base_uri: String, endpoints: String, destination: String, credentials: Hash
```

After that, the next common way would be with just parens:

```
required(base_uri: String, endpoints: String, destination: String, credentials: Hash)
```

After that, with both:  (which also would be necessary if you had params after the hash)

```
required({ base_uri: String, endpoints: String, destination: String, credentials: Hash})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no inconsistency. Ruby just use the same symbols `{}` for delimiting block of code and as a Hash constructor operator.

If appear as a proc/method argument, they are *always* considered as a block. By this reason you need to put a hash argument in parens to distinguish from block or pass directly hash elements as @Aetherus already mentioned.

Pretty consistent, if you'd ask me.